# phpunit eclipse configuration for test suite. documentation?

Tags: eclipse, testing, selenium, configuration, phpunit

I have difficulties to understand the complete process of configuring and creating phpunit test suite.

I would like to find readable, precise and clear instructions about creating phpunit test suite in eclipse. About Configuration, which libraries to use. If somebody can recommend something useful beside http://phpunit.de it would mean really alot.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to run PHPUnit tests in Eclipse, you need to install [MakeGood](http://piece-framework.com/projects/makegood/wiki) Eclipse plugin

Here is link to blog post how to setup whole thing [Running PHPUnit tests in Eclipse PDT](http://blog.loftdigital.com/running-phpunit-tests-in-eclipse-pdt)

Comment: the link to the blog post is is dead.